# Conditionally add where clause to leftJoin in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have some tables that are referencing users table in my database. So I want to get records of activities that occurred within a specified week in the different tables.

It shows that the week is `undefined` when I try to use `where` clause as shown below.

```
$week = 6;

$users = User::leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, week_number as week, SUM(amount) as performance_amount FROM performances GROUP BY week_number) AS p'), function ($join) {
      $join->on('p.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('p.week', $week);
    })
      ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, week_number as week, SUM(amount) as agent_amount FROM agents GROUP BY week_number) AS ag'), function ($join) {
        $join->on('ag.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('ag.week', $week);
      })
      ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(SELECT user_id, week_number as week, SUM(amount) as accumulative_amount FROM accumulatives GROUP BY week_number) AS ac'), function ($join) {
        $join->on('ac.user_id', '=', 'users.id')->where('ac.week', $week);
      })
    ->get();
```

When I hard-code the week value it returns the expected value but the rest of the records' week value returning  `null` as shown below.

[image: sample of the result]

Answer (score 2):

For all places like:

```
function ($join) {
```

you should make sure variable is visible like so:

```
function ($join) use ($week) {
```

You should read https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php for more details

Comment: Thanks, @Marcin Nabialek this your solutions does the job. However, it is showing null for the rest of the records aside from the first.